# Binary reading ID3 tag of mp3 file

Tags: c++, perl, binary, mp3, id3

I'am trying to read a mp3 file in c++ and show the id3 information that the file contains. The problem I have is when i read the frame header the size of the content that it holds is wrong. Instead of giving me a integer of 10 bytes it gives me 167772160 bytes.
http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_frame_overview

```
struct Header {
   char tag[3];
   char ver;
   char rev;
   char flags;
   uint8_t hSize[4];
};

struct ContentFrame 
{
   char id[4];
   uint32_t contentSize;
   char flags[2];
};

int ID3_sync_safe_to_int(uint8_t* sync_safe)
{
   uint32_t byte0 = sync_safe[0];
   uint32_t byte1 = sync_safe[1];
   uint32_t byte2 = sync_safe[2];
   uint32_t byte3 = sync_safe[3];

   return byte0 << 21 | byte1 << 14 | byte2 << 7 | byte3;
}

const int FRAMESIZE = 10;
```

The code above is used in order to translate the binary data to ASCCI data. 
**Inside of main**

```
Header header;
ContentFrame contentFrame;

ifstream file(argv[1], fstream::binary);
//Read header 
file.read((char*)&header, FRAMESIZE);

//This will print out 699 which is the correct filesize
cout << "Size: " << ID3_sync_safe_to_int(header.hSize) << endl << endl;

//Read frame header
file.read((char*)&contentFrame, FRAMESIZE);
//This should print out the frame size. 
cout << "Frame size: " << int(contentFrame.contentSize) << endl;
```

I have written a program for this task in **Perl** and it works fine, there unpack is used such as:

```
my($tag, $ver, $rev, $flags, $size) = unpack("Z3 C C C N"), "header");
my($frameID, $FrameContentSize, $frameFlags) = unpack("Z4 N C2", "content");
```

*sync_safe_to_int is also used in order to get the size of the header correct but for the contet size it is only to print witout any conversion*
*N An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.* 
*C  An unsigned char (octet) value.* 
*Z  A null-terminated (ASCIZ) string, will be null padded.*

The output from my program: 
 
Header content 
 
Tag: ID3 
 
Ver: 3 
 
Rev: 0 
 
Flags: 0 
 
Size: 699

**WRONG Output!**
Frame content 
 
ID: TPE1 
 
size: 167772160 
 
Flags:

**Correct output from Perl!**
Frame content 
 
ID: TPE1 
 
size: 10 
 
Flags: 0

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question. You say *"it gives me around 140000 bytes"* and then later on say you're seeing `size: 1677772160`. Is this a mistake or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It was a mistake from my side, It should have been correctet now.
The right output is 10, and the wrong output is 167772160. 
I'm sorry for the confusion about 1400000 that you can forget, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentFrame.contentSize` is defined as `uint32_t`, but printed as `(signed)int`.

Also, as the [document](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_overview)  states multibyte numbers are **Big Endian**:

> The bitorder in ID3v2 is most significant bit first (MSB). **The
>   byteorder in multibyte numbers is most significant byte first** (e.g.
>   $12345678 would be encoded $12 34 56 78).

No conversion is done for `contentFrame.contentSize` however. Those bytes should be reversed too, as in `ID3_sync_safe_to_int()`, but this time shifted in multiples of 8 instead of 7 (or use `ntohl()` - network-to-host order).

You say that you get 1677772160 instead of 18, but even with manipulation of the bits/bytes for the above, they don't seem to make sense. Are you sure those are the right numbers? On top of your post you have other values:

> Instead of giving me a low integear under 100 bytes it gives me around
>   140000 bytes.

Did you have a look at the bytes in memory after calling `file.read((char*)&contentFrame, FRAMESIZE);`? However if your ID shows `TPE1` the position should be ok. I just wonder if the numbers you provided are the correct ones, because they don't make sense.

Update with `nthol()` conversion:

```
//Read frame header
file.read((char*)&contentFrame, FRAMESIZE);
uint32_t frame_size = ntohl(contentFrame);
cout << "Frame size: " << frame_size << endl;
```

`ntohl()` will work on LE-systems *and* on BE-systems (on BE-systems it will simply do nothig).

Comment: I get 167772160 instead of 10. It was my bad. The numbers i have provided now should be the correct ones. I will try what you suggested!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly Big endian vs Little endian. All you need to do is reverse the bytes.

Comment: Also check out `ntohl()`.

Comment: Now I understand, the reason to use network long is beacuse its not hardware dependent. 
htonl() host to network long
ntohl() network to host long

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 1677772160 that you posted originally, the value you are getting is 167772160, which is 0x0A000000, which shows immediately that your bytes are reversed from the 0x0000000A (10 decimal) that you expect

You have arranged for Perl to read this in big-endian format using the N format, but your C code uses a simple `uint32_t`, which is hardware-dependent and presumably little-endian

You need to write a byte reversal subroutine for this field that behaves the same as your `ID3_sync_safe_to_int` for your header field but uses all 32 bits of the value. Something like this

```
uint32_t reverse_endian(uint32_t val)
{
   typedef union {
      uint32_t val;
      uint8_t byte[4];
   } split;

   split *original = (split *) &val;
   split new;

   new.byte[0] = original->byte[3];
   new.byte[1] = original->byte[2];
   new.byte[2] = original->byte[1];
   new.byte[3] = original->byte[0];

   return new.val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a clear description about the under lying problem. As Danny_ds pointed out there are a function that does this. ntohl() converts from network to host long

Answer (score 0):

okay I am not sure if you have interpreted your frame size in `ID3_sync_safe_to_int` method correctly.

Edit: I have no idea what causes this problem but you can read your framesize with fread separately or do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


struct Header {
   char tag[3];
   char ver;
   char rev;
   char flags;
   uint8_t hSize[4];
};

struct ContentFrame 
{
   char id[4];
   char contentSize[4];
   char flags[2];
};

int ID3_sync_safe_to_int(uint8_t* sync_safe)
{
   uint32_t byte0 = sync_safe[0];
   uint32_t byte1 = sync_safe[1];
   uint32_t byte2 = sync_safe[2];
   uint32_t byte3 = sync_safe[3];

   return byte0 << 21 | byte1 << 14 | byte2 << 7 | byte3;
}

const int FRAMESIZE = 10;
int main ( int argc, char  **argv )
{
Header header;
ContentFrame contentFrame;

ifstream file(argv[1], fstream::binary);
//Read header 
file.read((char*)&header, FRAMESIZE);

//This will print out 699 which is the correct filesize
cout << "Size: " << ID3_sync_safe_to_int(header.hSize) << endl << endl;

//Read frame header
file.read((char*)&contentFrame, FRAMESIZE);
//This should print out the frame size. 
int frame_size = (contentFrame.contentSize[3] & 0xFF) |
                    ((contentFrame.contentSize[2] & 0xFF) << 7 ) |
                    ((contentFrame.contentSize[1] & 0xFF) << 14 ) |
                    ((contentFrame.contentSize[0] & 0xFF) << 21 ); 
cout << "Frame size: " << frame_size << endl;

//cout << "Frame size: " << int(contentFrame.contentSize) << endl;
}
```

Comment: That field is in the header, and the most-significant bit is guaranteed to be zero. The value there is being retrieved correctly; It is the field  `contentSize` in the `ContentFrame` that is wrong, where all eight bits in each byte are significant